# Django Form Input Validation

Tags: python, django, forms

I have an input form defined as follows.

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'language', 
    ]
    widgets = {
        'language': forms.RadioSelect,
    }
```

Inside my `models.py` I define the following:

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
LANGUAGE = (('AR', 'Arabic'), ('FR', 'French'), ('ES', 'Spanish'))
language = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LANGUAGE, blank=False, default=None)
```

The first_name and last_name are required fields, and if the user leaves these two options empty, a warning message will prompt. However, I also want the `language` field to be a required field. To do so, I set `blank=False`. While it is correct that if you submit the form without selecting an option for `language`, the form will be invalid. However, it does not give the user a warning about it. How can this be done?

Comment: "To do so, I set blank=False": that's the default for any field, so no need to set that. Perhaps remove `default=None`, and use the `initial` parameter for your ModelForm?

Comment: Yea, I tried that, but no sucess :(

Comment: The validation warning shown to the user is something that you need to implement in your template HTML. Have you done that?

Comment: No I haven't done that, for the first_name, last_name it gives a warning with me having to do anything. I thought it would be possible for the radio button option as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#choices), if you set `blank=False`, you can not use `default=None`.

> Unless blank=False is set on the field along with a default then a label containing "---------" will be rendered with the select box. To override this behavior, add a tuple to choices containing None; e.g. (None, 'Your String For Display'). Alternatively, you can use an empty string instead of None where this makes sense - such as on a CharField.